# Plotting a Group Bar Plot with two columns in the dataframe in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a data frame with three columns: A range of Amount ($) (eg. $3,000-$3,999, $4,000 - $4,999), Percentage of Income, Percentage of Expenditure.

The x-axis would be the range of $ (as categorical) and for each range, I want to compare the percentage of income vs the percentage of expenditure. Hence, I would like to plot something like a group bar plot for comparison.

How do I do that in R?

Comment: Welcome to stack ! Please, provide a minimal reproducible example if you want help here, see [mcve]

Comment: Please check here first: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+grouped+bar+plot . If neither solution works, please share which code you tried and how the result you got differs from the result you want. Please add error messages and example data in an easy to use way (e.g. by pasting the output of `dput`).